# Query param array type in raml(0.8) in mule

Tags: arrays, mule, mule-studio, query-string, raml

I am getting one Get  request in which i have query param array type like below

https://localhost:8082/myapi/fetchids?ids=[1,2,3,4]

Now i have to define this array  query param in raml but still not get the solution.

My raml  look like below,  please advice what i have to write for array type query param in 0.8 version.

```
/fetchdetails:
  get:
   queryParameters:
       Ids:
        description: 'ids'
        type: integer
        required: true
        displayName: Ids
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no array type in RAML 0.8.

You can use *[array](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#array-type)* **on RAML 1** as the type for a query parameter.

For example:

```
/fetchdetails:
  get:
   queryParameters:
       ids:
        description: 'ids'
        type: integer[]
        required: true
```

which is a shorthand of:

```
/fetchdetails:
  get:
   queryParameters:
       ids:
        description: 'ids'
        type: array 
        items: integer
        required: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Christian Vogel in answer to [a similar question](http://forums.raml.org/t/array-type-as-a-queryparam/793/2), I think, on the RAML Community Forum said, "... you can't. The following types are allowed: string, number, integer, file, date, or boolean. What you could do is [use] a string and in your description say that it is a comma separated list for people discovering your API."

Comment: you are saying in way

/fetchdetails:
  get:
     queryParameters:
         ids:
         description: 'ids'
          type: String [ ]
          required: true

Comment: i didn't mean to imply array syntax in "... could do is [use] a", but was quoting exactly what was said in the forum except for the word "use" that I inserted as indicated by brackets. I think you need to use a string type in the RAML and document for users how to enter the comma separated list. Does that make sense?